# Play Framework 1.2: How to add custom module dependencies

Tags: java, dependencies, playframework

I'm a bit lost in a migration to Play 1.2. We have a set of custom
modules in our application. In Play 1.1.1 we used this structure:

```
/root/
  /module1
  /module2
  ...
  /moduleN
  /main app
```

And application.conf referenced the modules as a relative path *(../
module1)*

How can I do the same in Play 1.2? I see I should use the
*dependencies.yml* file, but can't find any information on this topic in
the official documentation.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** 
There is a lot of mixed information in the Google Group, but [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/msg/0187ab09586d4920) solved the issues.

I copy it here to provide future reference for people searching this issue in SO:

> Ok, using the latest from master, here the needed dependencies.yml
>   with comments inline:

```
# Application dependencies

# Notes:
#   play is an alias for play -> play $currentVersion
#   play -> crud is an alias for play -> crud $currentVersion
#   play -> secure is an alias for play -> secure $currentVersion
#   Modules from the main repository use 'play' as organisation
#

require:
    - play
    - play -> crud
    - play -> secure
    - play -> recaptcha 1.02
    - play -> greenscript 1.2b
    - crionics -> cms 1.0
    - ugot -> widgets 1.0
    - org.markdownj -> markdownj 0.3.0-1.0.2b4

repositories:

    - Scala Tools:
        type:       iBiblio
        root:       http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/
        contains:
            - org.markdownj

    - My modules:
        type:       local
        artifact:   /somewhere/on/your/disk/[organisation]/[module]-[revision]

        # This folder must contain
        # /somewhere/on/your/disk/crionics/cms-1.0
        # /somewhere/on/your/disk/ugot/widgets-1.0

        contains:
            - ugot
            - crionics
```

**NOTE:** be aware that if you do something wrong with the local repository settings you risk deleting your project (completely!) when running *play deps* . Yes, it happened to me :(

Comment: it doesn't work for me. I get a `mystuff->mystuff ->` missing when requiring `mystuff -> users 1.0` from artifact path `/path/to/repos/[organisation]/[module]-[revision]` which contains `/path/to/repos/mystuff/users-1.0`

Comment: @Yanick I would recommend you to add a new question on this, attaching the content of your dependencies file in the question

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35773136/1023151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give the information to other people who are not subscribers of the play google group, to find such information, go on play google group https://groups.google.com/group/play-framework and search "module + local", you should find some clue...

Comment: The play group has some misleading posts, but this one solved the issues: http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/msg/0187ab09586d4920. I added the solution to the question as for future reference.

Comment: just keep in mind that when your module uses organization "play", you have to put it in PLAY_PATH/modules

Comment: redirecting to another forum with no minimal answer here nor a concrete reference to an answer in the other forum feels unpolite