# How to reference local modules using dependency.yml?

Tags: playframework

How to reference local modules using **dependency.yml**

Thought I would just drop this question as it shows in the forums on a regular basis. Answer should follow.

Take the following application hierarchy:

```
myplayapp/
myfirstmodule/
mysecondmodule/
```

I am running my application using ***play run myplayapp***

How can I reference my local modules using Play 1.2 dependency.xml?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856747/play-framework-1-2-how-to-add-custom-module-dependencies

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easy!

Edit file **myplayapp/conf/dependencies.yml** as follows

```
require:
    - play
    - myfirstmodule -> myfirstmodule
    - mysecondmodule -> mysecondmodule

repositories:
    - My modules:
        type:       local
        artifact:   ${application.path}/../[module]
        contains:
            - myfirstmodule
            - mysecondmodule
```

then run ***play dependencies myplayapp*** and you are done.

Note: be careful, not to use '-' in the module name, it is a reserved delimiter for the version number.
Ie. myfirstmodule-1.00  or myfirstmodule-head

Comment: Do you know how to make it work with the play war command? As it turns out, /tmp/myplayapp/WEB-INF/application/modules/myfirstmodule is an empty directory. Tried with 1.2.5 and 1.2.7

Answer (score 3):

You can also drop it inside the modules directory, like we used to do on ${play.path}/modules, if you have problems with dependencies.yml somehow.

Comment: in this case, don't you have to use organization "play" for your module?

Comment: a deps --sync will delete it, it seems