# Copy Play! core module into app via "deps"

Tags: module, dependencies, playframework

Play will normally reference core modules such as `crud` and `secure` out of the Play installation directory. Is there any way to force these dependencies to be copied to my project `modules` directory when I run `play deps`?

Our deployment process requires that all app resources be available inside the project directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1.2.x branch of Play on GitHub now contains an option to force Play core modules to be copied into project directory:

```
play deps --forceCopy
```

This should copy modules like `secure` and `crud` into your project directory.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will need to copy them into your own local repository and use the dependencies file to import them. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856747/play-framework-1-2-how-to-add-custom-module-dependencies) (question has solution in it) on how to do it