# PlayFramework private repos

Tags: playframework

I m currently setting up play in my agency. I'd like to do some gouvernance with the module the developpers can use.
Is it possible to host mirror repositories of the Play modules and Maven library and to configure play to only use these repositories?
I have read this [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/dependency) but I didn't see how to do it?

Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 2):

The key for me getting play to use my nexus repository rather than mavenCentral was to name my nexus repository in dependencies.yml as "mavenCentral":

```
repositories:
    - mavenCentral:
        type: iBiblio 
        root: "http://nexus.mydomain.com/nexus/content/groups/public/"
        contains:
            - com -> *
            - org -> *
            - play -> *
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own local (custom) module repositories for Play, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856747/play-framework-1-2-how-to-add-custom-module-dependencies). On Maven dependencies, you can just deploy your own [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) server (or equivalent).

This would let you limit the modules the devs can use.

You could also flag the dependencies.yml file in your repository as "read only" (assuming your source code repository allows it), so you can use the existing sources for modules and Jars (official Play, Maven) but devs can't change dependencies.

Comment: I already did this but Play is still going to central repos, so I do not know how to modify this behavior.

Comment: @Xavier if you set up a repository source, and use it, it shouldn't go to central repos. Unless you are using play -> module, which is not the correct configuration (see again the link I posted)