# Adding Oracle Jdbc driver to Playframework dependency.yml file

Tags: playframework

I tried to setup a local repository so that I can full use the play dependency command.  However there is no public repo for Oracle's JDBC drivers.  So I though I could do this

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play 1.2.3
    - play -> table 1.2
    - com.oracle -> ojdbc14_g 10.0

repositories:

    - playVendorDependencies:
        type:       local
        artifact:   "${application.path}/tmplib/[artifact].jar"
        contains:   com.oracle -> *
```

But it is not working - says that the ojdbc14_g.jar file is not found in any repo.  running with play dependencies --debug does not seem to show that the new repo is ever accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a couple of errors, try this:

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play 1.2.3
    - play -> table 1.2
    - com.oracle -> ojdbc14_g 10.0

repositories:

    - playVendorDependencies:
        type:       local
        artifact:   "${application.path}/tmplib/[organization]/[module]_[revision]"
        contains:  
          - com.oracle -> *
```

and make sure your path exists and is:

```
${application.path}/tmplib/com.oracle/ojdbc14_g_10.0.jar
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856747/play-framework-1-2-how-to-add-custom-module-dependencies) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the reply -- my final file is

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play 1.2.3
    - play -> table 1.2
    - com.oracle -> ojdbc14_g 10.0

repositories:

    - playVendorDependencies:
        type:       local
        artifact:   "${application.path}/tmplib/[artifact].jar"
        contains:
             - com.oracle -> *
```

See the difference?  The contains clause at the bottom needed a line feed, spaces and a dash to be proper YAML format.