# How can I configure the play framework to use my artifactory repository for all dependencies?

Tags: playframework, artifactory

I am trying to add a local maven repository that I have set up using artifactory which I use to cache maven repositories.  Following the [dependency instructions](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/dependency) I have found how to set up a repository with a contains attribute that scopes what the repository has.  What I would like to do is have this repository used for everything, is there a way to configure that?

```
repositories:
    - artifactory:  
        type:       iBiblio
        artifact:   "http://myartifactoryhost.com/artifactory/libs-release"
        contains:
            - foo-bars -> *
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the following to $HOME/.ivy2/ivysettings.xml

This will make ivy (and therefore play dependency resolution) first look in local maven repo and then use your repo manager (similar to mirrorOf * in .m2/settings.xml).

```
<ivy-settings>
    <!-- path to local maven repo and default maven layout -->
    <property name="local-maven2-pattern" value="${user.home}/.m2/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision]" override="false" />
    <!-- set resolver chain as default -->
    <settings defaultResolver="main" />
    <!-- configure caches -->
    <caches repositoryCacheDir="${user.home}/.ivy2/cache">
        <!-- do not cache from local .m2-->
        <cache name="nocache" useOrigin="true" />
        <cache name="default" />
    </caches>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="main">
            <!-- as this is not cached, even changing SNAPSHOT dependencies are resolved correctly -->
            <filesystem name="local-maven-2" m2compatible="true" local="true" cache="nocache">
                <ivy pattern="${local-maven2-pattern}.pom" />
                <artifact pattern="${local-maven2-pattern}(-[classifier]).[ext]" />
            </filesystem>
            <!-- use repository manager as proxy to maven-central (and alle other repositories)--> 
            <ibiblio name="repomanager" m2compatible="true"root="http://your.repomanager.intra/path/to/repo" cache="default"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivy-settings>
```

Comment: This is the Example 3 @ http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/dependency. Is there a way to let it use the .m2/settings.xml so I don't have to repeat info about the repo manager?

Comment: As time of writing i had opened a merge request on github altering the documentation but it hasn't been online then... I don't know a way to reuse settings.xml, i'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the [local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856747/play-framework-1-2-how-to-add-custom-module-dependencies) configuration and put everything in there. In your case the local repo would point to your artifacts host.

Be aware you can't replace the "play" entry, although you can add local copies of modules to your repository to use them.