# play framework artifactory service unavailable

Tags: playframework, ivy, artifactory

I'm using play 2.4 and I've added this line to build.sbt:

```
resolvers += "artifactory-libs-release"   at "http://host.company.com:8080/artifactory/libs-release"
```

and then added my dependency to the libraryDependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    ...,
    "com.company" % "JavaUtils" % "0.0.3"
)
```

But when i run the compile task it says

```
[info] Resolving com.company#JavaUtils;0.0.3 ...
[error] SERVER ERROR: Service Unavailable url=http://host.company.com:8080/artifactory/libs-release/com/company/JavaUtils/0.0.3/JavaUtils-0.0.3.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.company#JavaUtils;0.0.3
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/user/.ivy2/local/com.company/JavaUtils/0.0.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   /home/user/dev/Tools/activator-1.3.5-minimal/repository/com.company/JavaUtils/0.0.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/company/JavaUtils/0.0.3/JavaUtils-0.0.3.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/company/JavaUtils/0.0.3/JavaUtils-0.0.3.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.company/JavaUtils/0.0.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== artifactory-libs-release: tried
[warn]   http://host.company.com:8080/artifactory/libs-release/com/company/JavaUtils/0.0.3/JavaUtils-0.0.3.pom
```

However when wget'ting the url `http://host.company.com:8080/artifactory/libs-release/com/company/JavaUtils/0.0.3/JavaUtils-0.0.3.pom` it resolves and downloads perfectly fine.

I've already tried configuring ivy like here [How can I configure the play framework to use my artifactory repository for all dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729119/how-can-i-configure-the-play-framework-to-use-my-artifactory-repository-for-all) but that didn't change anything.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to pass a proxy when accessing http://host.company.com:8080 ?

Comment: No, it's in the same network as my machine.

Comment: And is SBT configured to pass a proxy?

Comment: I didn't configure any proxy settings in the project, so unless it pulls some proxy config from my environment variables (needed to access hosts outside this network) it's not. Where would i check if it's configured to use a proxy?