# How does one add another source directory to a Play 1.2.x project?

Tags: java, playframework, thrift, playframework-1.x

I am using the play framework (v1.2.3).  As part of my code, I have various generated source files.  These files are generated by thrift, so I do not want them included in my source control.  As such, I want to exclude all of the generated files.  But, currently, I am building them all under the main app/ directory.  So there is no way to add an ignore clause to avoid committing any of the files into git.

This would not be a problem if I could simply generate the thrift source files into a different directory structure (e.g. gen/).  Is there a way to configure Play to compile files from the app/ folder and from another separate, unrelated folder altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your best option is to provide those files as a [module](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/modules) and use it from the main application. That way you'll have them in a separated area.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856747/play-framework-1-2-how-to-add-custom-module-dependencies) about how to add local modules to your project.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I will give this approach a try.